# The BlackBerry Simulator rises a RuntimeException

Tags: cordova, runtime-error, blackberry-simulator

I'm trying to run a BlackBerry project using Phonegap.
I followed all the steps [described here](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting+Started+with+PhoneGap-BlackBerry+with+the+Latest+Environment).
When I run the project, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Development\eclipse_galileo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\TaskBlackBerry deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\TaskBlackBerry.rapc -sourceroot=C:\Users\Admin\workspace\TaskBlackBerry\src;C:\Users\Admin\workspace\TaskBlackBerry\res -import=C:\Users\Admin\Development\eclipse_galileo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\Users\Admin\workspace\TaskBlackBerry\bin
C:\Users\Admin\Development\eclipse_galileo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar(net_rim_json_org.cod): Error!: Duplicate definition for 'org.json.me.JSONArray' found in: C:\Users\PCLAVAL12\workspace\TaskBlackBerry\src\org\json\me\JSONArray.java
Packaging project TaskBlackBerry failed (took 4.206 seconds)
```

Si, I removed the org.json.me that contains the JSONArray.java (because the JSONArray class is called by the other files, so deleting only this file will generate several errors) and no error rose.

But, on the BlackBerry Emulator, I get the following exception :

```
JVM Error 104
Uncaught:RuntimeException
```

Can you help me?

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: Which PhoneGap version are you using, and which BlackBerry framework (Java or Widgets)?

Comment: I downloaded this version: http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-blackberry. Then, I first tried the 6.0 JRE which returns the error described above. I tried the others JREs (4.6.1, 4.6.0, ..) thant lauches the simulator without problems but don't upload the app into it!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from BB 5 OS, org.json.me is included in SDK itself and you need not to import external jar or Java classes. Just import org.json.me and use it. Happy coding

Comment: Consider adding a link to the documentation, where it points this change